# How to mock IHttpClientFactory using typed clients

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to properly add `HttpClient` in my app while also allowing for mocking away the client factory for unit testing purposes. I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients) as as resource.

In my **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHttpClient<IUploader, Uploader>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        if (somecheckismet)
            return new HttpClientHandler() { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; } };
        return new HttpClientHandler();
    });
```

And my **Uploader.cs**

```
public class Uploader : IUploader
{
    private readonly HttpClient m_httpClient;

    public Uploader(HttpClient client)
    {
        m_httpClient = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadData(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result;
        try
        {
            result = await m_httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
            if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return "Some error message;
            }
            else
            {
                return null; // Success!
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Uh-oh!";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to dependency inject `HttpClient` into the `Uploader`. However, now that I've done this, how do I go about unit testing the `Uploader`? Previously, it would have worked to dependency inject `HttpClientHandler` which can be mocked away. However, now since I am trying to use `IHttpClientFactory`, it seems that I have to inject `HttpClient`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp

Comment: I did a video using `HttpClient` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMxQlgOH7cg).  Perhaps it could provide some insights or give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just continue mocking the `HttpClientHandler` and use it to create the `HttpClient`

```
public void TestMethod() 
{
    var handler = // Mock the HttpClientHandler;
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var uploader = new Uploader(client);

    // Draw the rest of the owl
}
```

Comment: What if you need a real httpclient made by the factory? I'm trying to test if my code correctly sets up the polly policies using the httpclient factory. To test that, I need to get a __real_ httpclient from the _real_ factory, but I would like for that client to have a mocked handler so I can artificially pass/fail my web requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to moq your `HttpClientFactory`. `HttpClientFactory` is just a helper class that returns `HttpClient` instances from a pool.  In a unit testing scenario you are going to setup the `HttpClient` instance directly.  Your startup.cs never enters the picture because you aren't starting up your entire application.

Your `Uploader` class is already setup for unit testing in that your are passing in your `HttpClient` instance.  To unit test around `HttpClient`, you don't moq out the `HttpClient` instance, but replace the `HttpMessageHandler` that `HttpClient` uses. 
Here's a [link](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/) to a great post on all the details

Code lifted directly from the article

```
// ARRANGE
var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
handlerMock
   .Protected()
   // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
   .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
      "SendAsync",
      ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
      ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
   )
   // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
   .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
   {
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
      Content = new StringContent("[{'id':1,'value':'1'}]"),
   })
   .Verifiable();

// use real http client with mocked handler here
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/"),
};

var subjectUnderTest = new MyTestClass(httpClient);

// ACT
var result = await subjectUnderTest
   .GetSomethingRemoteAsync('api/test/whatever');

// ASSERT
result.Should().NotBeNull(); // this is fluent assertions here...
result.Id.Should().Be(1);

// also check the 'http' call was like we expected it
var expectedUri = new Uri("http://test.com/api/test/whatever");

handlerMock.Protected().Verify(
   "SendAsync",
   Times.Exactly(1), // we expected a single external request
   ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
      req.Method == HttpMethod.Get  // we expected a GET request
      && req.RequestUri == expectedUri // to this uri
   ),
   ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

Comment: What if you need a real httpclient made by the factory? I'm trying to test if my code correctly sets up the polly policies using the httpclient factory. To test that, I need to get a _real_ httpclient from the _real_ factory, but I would like for that client to have a _mocked_ handler so I can artificially pass/fail my web requests.